# mysql delete duplicated rows that not exist in another table

Tags: mysql, records

Working in a database of a hospital.
I have a table of patients, and another that contains the medical records.
the table medical records, has the patient_id.
by an error in the system, many patients have been inserted twice or more, with the same id.
I'm trying to make a mysql query that allows me to remove/check the patients repeated in the patient table, but only if the patient_id is not in the table of medical records.

something like this:

```
(select * from patients group by id having count(id)>1 as p)
 where patient_id not in (select patient_id from history)
```

the above query is symbolic and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to select all duplicate `patients` not in `history` is using `where not exists`:

```sql
select p.id
from patients p

where not exists (
  select h.patient_id 
  from history h 
  where h.patient_id=p.id
)
group by p.id having count(p.id) > 1
```

Another way is using `not in`:

```
select id
from patients

where id not in (
  select patient_id from Posts 
  WHERE patient_id IS NOT NULL
  group by patient_id
)
group by id having count(id) > 1
```